# Convert Decimal to int in Crystal Report Formula

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

i have used formula to generate a RowNumber for each Record
formula is like this:

`shared numbervar rownum;
rownum := rownum + 1;
rownum;`

But it displays decimal numbers : 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00
i want to display only Int numbers in RowNumber : 1,2,3,4,5

how can i do this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you receive a valid answer, you should Accept it, to mark you question as Replied and to thank the person who gave you the proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the formula field on the canvas, then click the Decrease Decimals toolbar icon twice.

You should the RecordNumber field instead of incrementing a variable--much less work.